# MIPS recursive approach to finding the distance between two strings

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I'm having trouble writing a recursive function in MIPS assembly to calculate the distance between two strings. The function should take four parameters: `string_a`, `string_b`, `length_string_a`, `length_string_b` and return the distance between the two strings. For example `findDistance("Sun", "Son", 3, 3)` should `return 1`, which is the number of times the first string needs to be changed to resemble the second. The function should `return -1` if the length of each of the two strings is less than 0

Here is what I had attempted before I went blank. I just need someone to point me in the right direction and I can finish it

```
.data

string_a: .ascii "Sun"

string_b: .ascii "Son"

length_str_a: .word 3

length_str_b: .word 3





.text

#copy starting address of each of the strings to registers

la $a0, string_a

la $a1, string_b

lw $a2, length_str_a

lw $a3, length_str_b



#call function findDistance



jal findDistance



#The function findDistance

findDistance:



#if length of strings <= 0 jump to error, else continue to find distance



#define base class





#recursive



#in the case that the lengths are 0 or less

error:

li $v0, -1

j return

#retun    
return:

j $ra
```

Comment: If I were you I would use this site: https://godbolt.org/. Write the desired code in C and see how it would look.

Comment: let me have a look

Comment: @Eraklon the code compiles but can't seem to run on MARS

Comment: Well I would not try copy paste it but rahter try to understand and replicate the interesting part. Get an idea how it look like.

Comment: You'll want to compile with `-O1` or `-Og` if you want to read and understand it.  And @Eraklon: you also need to use `-fno-delayed-branch` to only fill branch-delay slots with NOPs, not other instructions that are expected to run.  MARS simulates (by default) a MIPS without branch delay slots at all, but having NOPs after branches isn't harmful.